# Add a hook to wp_mail() to track Google Analytics Event

Tags: wp-mail, google-analytics

I hope you'll be able to help me on this one: 
I'm trying to trigger a GA event for every email sent via a Wordpress site. 
My idea was to add the following code to my child theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action("wp_mail", "trigger_contact_event");
function trigger_contact_event(){
include "include/Galvanize.php"; //Galvanize is a php class able to trigger GA events server-side
$GA = new Galvanize('UA-XXXXXXX-XX');
$GA->trackEvent("Contact", "info request");
}
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't trigger anything. 
Would anyone have a solution? Even another way to trigger a GA event, as long as it is hooked to any email sent via the wordpress website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't believe wp_mail fires an action called wp_mail.  You can find the function in wp-includes/pluggable.php.  There are numerous filters throughout the function and I know it fires the phpmailer_init action.

Comment: while there isn't an action named `wp_mail`, there is a filter, and it *should* run your code (though it's not really the appropriate place to do so). you can test this by putting `die` in your function and doing something that results in sending of mail.

Comment: `wp_mail` is a pluggable function, so you could just copy the whole function from the `wp-includes/pluggable.php` file and put than into a plugin. And then, at the very end of the `wp_mail` function (on your plugin), put your tracking code.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `phpmailer_init` (unless you're using a plugin that overrides `wp_mail`):

```
function trigger_contact_event( $phpmailer ) {
    // See PHPMailer class for available properties & methods if you need
    // information about the email being sent.
}

add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'trigger_contact_event' );
```